# grunt imagemin gives : Minified 0 images..?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

As I enter **grunt imagemin** it gives as a result : 'Minified 0 images'

What I did:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --save-dev
```

Installed imagemin plug-in

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

imagemin:{
  dynamic:{
    files: [{
      expand:true,
      cwd: 'images/',
      src: ['**/*.{png,jpg}'],
      dest: 'images/build'
    }]
  }
}

});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'imagemin']);

};
```

Changed Grunt.js file configuration

```
grunt imagemin
```

Entered on terminal..

Why wouldn't it optimize the images?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `--verbose` flag is useful for debugging issues like this. What is the output if the task with that option added?

Answer (score 0):

I found it..

I had a wrong path..

```
imagemin:{
  dynamic:{
  files: [{
  expand:true,
  cwd: 'images/',   // This had to be img/
  src: ['**/*.{png,jpg}'],
  dest: 'images/build'
  }]
}
}
```

Plus, I don't set concat and uglify plugin above so default tasks definition was wrong too

```
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'imagemin']);
```

must be

```
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
```